# Why am I unable to use [R] with VS Code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Problem: I cannot get the R interpreter to run inside of VS Code on Windows 10. I keep getting errors, like "R:(not attached)". Here is what I tried to fix the problem myself:

I tried uninstalling both visual studio code and my installation of R (v 4-1.0). I then  used CCleaner Professional to cleanup my registry. I restarted my machine. I then reinstalled R-4.1.0 accepting all of the default choices (especially writing the version number to the registry). Next, I installed the package `languageserver`. I then re-installed VS Code (latest stable version). I tried installing vscDebugger, but I received an error stating that it is not available for this version of R. Within VS Code, I tried running the command `R Debugger: Update or install the required R package`. When I invoke the procedure, it throws an error indicating that --no-restore is not recognized and is an unexpected token. Here is the code and error Visual Studio Code generates when I execute `R Debugger: Update or install the required R package`.

PS C:\Users\Dad\Documents\Learn++\Projects\AdvancedR> "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" --no-restore --quiet -f "c:\Users\Dad.vscode\extensions\rdebugger.r-debugger-0.4.7\R\install.R" --args "https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/releases/download/v0.4.7/vscDebugger_0.4.7.zip"

"At line:1 char:52

- "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" --no-restore --quiet ...
- ```
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token 'no-restore' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1

- "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" --no-restore --quiet ...
- 

The '--' operator works only on variables or on properties.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
ge`:"

I do not know what to try next to get the R interpreter to work with VS Code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Has it never worked for you (i.e. this is your first time setting it up)? Have you installed Yuki Ueda's R extension as well? Is the "R: not attached" message showing up in the console terminal or on the bottom status bar (if the latter, what happens if you click on it and try to attach it?? What do your JSON Settings look like (View > Command Palette > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)?

Answer (score -2):

Tried to install it from vsc extension menu just search R then install it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).